# Binary multiplication without arithmetic operators and loops

Tags: c, binary, multiplication

I have to do the following task:

> Implement written multiplication of two two-digit binary numbers
> without using the `+`, `-`, `*`, `/` and bit operations. The logical
> operators `&&`, `||` and `!` may only be applied to logical expressions and
> not to the numbers themselves. The use of arrays and loops is not
> permitted here. Likewise, the solution by distinguishing between all
> 16 cases is not permitted here.
>
> The code should be structured in such a way that an extension to
> numbers with a larger number of digits is easily possible.
>
> The two numbers are entered digit by digit from the console or via
> redirection from a file (exactly four digits). For single-digit
> numbers, the leading zero must also be entered.
>
> To do this, use two functions `add()`, which adds two binary digits
> without carry (i.e. returns 0 or 1) and `carry()`, which determines the
> carry when adding two binary digits. Additional functions may be used.
>
> The output should be such that the two factors are next to each other
> without leading zeros, then an equal sign follows and the product
> without leading zeros.

My approach is Booth's algorithm for multiplication with binary numbers. However, I don't know how to implement this without loops.

Do I have the right algorithm?

Code example of the mentioned algorithm:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// Function to display a binary number
void displayBinary(int n) {
    if (n == 0) {
        printf("0");
        return;
    }

    int binary[32];
    int i = 0;

    while (n > 0) {
        binary[i] = n % 2;
        n /= 2;
        i++;
    }

    for (i--; i >= 0; i--) {
        printf("%d", binary[i]);
    }
}

// Function to perform Booth multiplication
int boothMultiplication(int multiplicand, int multiplier) {
    int m = multiplicand;
    int q = multiplier;
    int ac = 0; // Accumulator
    int q0 = 0; // Least significant bit of q
    int q1 = 0; // Next least significant bit of q

    int n = sizeof(int) * 8; // Number of bits in an integer 

    printf("Step\t\tA\t\tQ\t\tQ(-1)\tQ(0)\tOperation\n");

    for (int step = 1; step <= n; step++) {
        int q0_q1 = (q0 << 1) | q1;
        int operation = 0;

        if ((q0_q1 & 0b11) == 0b01) {
            ac += m;
            operation = 1;
        } else if ((q0_q1 & 0b11) == 0b10) {
            ac -= m;
            operation = -1;
        }

        if (q & 1) {
            q1 = q0;
        }
        q0 = q & 1;
        q >>= 1;

        printf("%d\t\t\t", step);
        displayBinary(ac);
        printf("\t");
        displayBinary(q);
        printf("\t");
        displayBinary(q1);
        printf("\t");
        displayBinary(q0);
        printf("\t");

        if (operation == 1) {
            printf("Addition (+%d)\n", m);
        } else if (operation == -1) {
            printf("Subtraction (-%d)\n", m);
        } else {
            printf("No Operation\n");
        }
    }

    return ac;
}

int main() {
    int multiplicand, multiplier;
    
    printf("Enter the multiplicand: ");
    scanf("%d", &multiplicand);
    
    printf("Enter the multiplier: ");
    scanf("%d", &multiplier);

    int product = boothMultiplication(multiplicand, multiplier);

    printf("\nResult: %d * %d = %d\n", multiplicand, multiplier, product);

    return 0;
}
```

[The original task in German](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxEjP.png)

Comment: Which operations are considered "bit operations"? Please clarify.

Comment: Could you unroll the loops?

Comment: You haven't shown what you have as an algorithm, so we can't tell whether you have the right algorithm.  This seems like a perverse exercise, but I suppose it will probably teach you the basics of computer addition and multiplication of integers.  Are the two-digit numbers unsigned or are you supposed to use 2's-complement arithmetic?  What size is the result supposed to be — 2, 3, 4 or more digits?

Comment: Since the inputs are fixed-size, you don't need loops. Just 4 variables (or 2 two-element arrays) for the input digits, and enough similar variables for the results and intermediate carries. Then just hard-code all the calculations on these digits.

Comment: They are two 2-digit binary numbers, hence it can be solved without loops.

Comment: If you are not allowed to use loops, the only way I can think of to allow to "easily" extend this to more digits is by using recursion instead.

Comment: Have you made up a "truth table" for the 16 input/output combinations? What does that reveal?

Comment: @Immet09, "My approach is Booth's algorithm for multiplication with binary numbers. " --> post the code that implements that approach, even if loops are involved.

Comment: @njuffa "bit operations" ar AND, OR, XOR, Not, etc.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I added a code example (made with AI cause I don't have a clue) of Booth's algorithm for binary multiplication. I also added a picture with the original task, which is in German.  The numbers which get first entered and then multiplyed should be usigned - not negative and in binary - and 4 digits.

Comment: @Barmar I thought about hard-coding but it isnt allowed :(

Comment: The original task tells which algorithm to use (_written multiplication_). Booth's algorithm is more complex, and I wonder how you'd get _the value of (**−m**)_ if the unary `-` as well as a bit operation isn't allowed.

Comment: @mkrieger1 thanks, recursion could / should be the way to do it ^^

Comment: @JonathanLeffler nvm. 2 digits each so only 11, 10, 01, 00 should be possible to enter

Comment: The "and bit operations" requirement makes it impossible to implement add(). You cannot reasonably implement binary addition in C without either + or bitwise operators.

Comment: _`add()`, which adds two binary digits without carry (i.e. returns 0 or 1)_ can easily be implemented: `int add(int b1, int b0) { return b1 != b0; }`.

Comment: You're not allowed to use a loop, and you're not allowed to hard-code variables or array indexes. What else is there?

Comment: @Immet09 – 
It is a misconception that _hard-coding_ _isnt allowed_ - the term _hard-coding_ isn't even defined or mentioned in the task description.

Comment: @Armali with this part "Likewise, the solution by distinguishing between all 16 cases is not permitted here." hard-coding was forbidden.

Comment: Only _distinguishing between all 16 cases is not permitted_ - that does not preclude any other form of hard-coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should satisfy the requirements.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int add(int b1, int b0) { return b1 != b0; }

int carry(int b1, int b0) { return b1==1 && b0==1; }

void print(int b3, int b2, int b1, int b0, char *s)
{
    int c = 0;
    if (b3==1 || c) printf("%i", b3), c = 1;
    if (b2==1 || c) printf("%i", b2), c = 1;
    if (b1==1 || c) printf("%i", b1), c = 1;
    printf("%i%s", b0, s), c = 1;
}

int main()
{
    int x1, x0, y1, y0, z3, z2, z1, z0, a1, a0;
    scanf("%i", &x1),   scanf("%i", &x0); 
    scanf("%i", &y1),   scanf("%i", &y0); 
    z1 = y0 ? x1 : 0,   z0 = y0 ? x0 : 0;
    a1 = y1 ? x1 : 0,   a0 = y1 ? x0 : 0;
    z2 = carry(z1, a0), z1 = add(z1, a0);
    z3 = carry(z2, a1), z2 = add(z2, a1);
    print( 0,  0, x1, x0, " * "),
    print( 0,  0, y1, y0, " = "),
    print(z3, z2, z1, z0, "\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have the following bits: **a**, **b**, **c**, and **d**. These bits can only be 0 or 1 each.

You are trying to multiply **ab** * **cd** to produce a 4-bit value of **wxyz**

```
ab * cd  ==  wzyz (decimal)
---------------------------
00 * 00  ==  0000 (0)
00 * 01  ==  0000 (0)
00 * 10  ==  0000 (0)
00 * 11  ==  0000 (0)
01 * 00  ==  0000 (0)
01 * 01  ==  0001 (1)
01 * 10  ==  0010 (2)
01 * 11  ==  0011 (3)
10 * 00  ==  0000 (0)
10 * 01  ==  0010 (2)
10 * 10  ==  0100 (4)
10 * 11  ==  0110 (6)
11 * 00  ==  0000 (0)
11 * 01  ==  0011 (3)
11 * 10  ==  0110 (6)
11 * 11  ==  1001 (9)
```

If you put all this into a [Karnaugh map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map). You'll deduce the following boolean logic for computing w,x,y, and z:

```
    w = a & b & c & d;
    x = (a & c) & ~(a & b & c & d);
    y = ((a & d) | (b & c)) & ~(a & b & c & d);
    z = b & d;
```

Or simply:

```
    w = a & b & c & d;
    x = (a & c) & ~w;
    y = ((a & d) | (b & c)) & ~w;
    z = b & d;
```

And the final result can be computed as this:

```
int result = (w << 3) | (x << 2) | (y << 1) | z;
```

I don't think this satisfies the requirement of extensibility to larger bit input set or is implemented with the add/carry approach discussed. But I'm putting it out here as a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

Just make a look-up table. Example using C23 binary notation:

```c
unsigned int mul (unsigned int a, unsigned int b)
{
  // look-up table usage: [a][b] gives a * b
  static const unsigned int LUT [0b11 + 1][0b11 + 1] =
  {
    [0b00] = { [0b00] = 0, [0b01] = 0, [0b10] = 0, [0b11] = 0, },
    [0b01] = { [0b00] = 0, [0b01] = 1, [0b10] = 2, [0b11] = 3, },

    // and so on...
  };

  return LUT[a][b];
}
```

Comment: How can this easily be extended to numbers with more digits? Do you suggest to write out 256 multiplication results when multiplying two 4-bit numbers?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I didn't make up the artificial requirements. I'd suggest writing `a * b` . The whole challenge seems to be an exercise in reading the teacher's mind, since they seem to have a very specific solution in mind...

Comment: Yet another solution is taking the input as strings and creating a unique hash for a hash table. Convoluted C programming 101.

Comment: @Lundin How do you calculate the hash of an arbitrary length string without a loop?